# Activation date is not set when a key is rotated through Rotation Policy in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-security, azure-secrets

I have created a Key in Azure Key Vault with Activation date and Expiration date.
Also configured Rotation Policy and enabled auto rotation. Please refer to the attached screenshot.

[image: Key Rotation Policy]

When I clicked on "Rotate now", a new version of the key is created but the Activation date is not set. Have a look at the below screen shot.

[image: Key Versions]

How to set the activation date when a key is rotated / auto rotated automatically (without manual intervention)? What am I missing here?

Kindly help.

Comment: I imagine, it you click rotate or when rotating automatically the new key is enabled and active immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created a key and configured rotation policy with same settings as yours like below:

[image]

**When I tried to rotate it, even I can see Activation Date as Null like below:**

[image]

I agree with **Thomas** that if you are clicking rotate now manually or rotating automatically, the new key will be enabled and active immediately.

**So, if you want Activation date you have to manually set it like below:**

[image]

**After setting it manually, Activation Date displayed like below:**

[image]